# Tiktok instant publishing

Tags: tiktok, tiktok-api

Some social media scheduling tools are already publishing instantly to TikTok. I noticed they have the `video.publish` scope in there oauth url:

tiktok.com/auth/authorize?client_key=awyzerp78dw85x&response_type=code&scope=video.publish&redirect_uri=domain.com

However, when I try this It keeps telling me the scope is not correct. When I look what the available scopes are I do not see `video.publish`.

How is it possible I do not read anything about `video.publish`, but social media scheduling tools are using this. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Why not ask TikTok's developer support about this?